# How to setup heroku plugin with intellij IDEA?

Tags: heroku, intellij-idea

I recently started using the IntelliJ Ultimate IDE. I have the version 13.1.2 and I would want to work on heroku using this. I came across this [link](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6659?pr=idea&offset=15&max=15#comments_pan) and downloaded the plugin.

I installed the plugin as well. I am not able to figure out where I can configure the account. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings... -> IDE Settings -> Heroku

Comment: Not anymore :( Now you can set it up when creating a run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Clouds, then, click in the plus icon.